# lightdm change badge icon login for "ubuntu on wayland"

Tags: unity, login, icons, lightdm, cinnamon

I have changed cinnamon login badge icon with:

```
/usr/share/unity-greeter/custom_cinnamon_badge.png
```

I would like to change the "ubuntu on wayland" badge (which is empty) in the same way, for example with a file similar to:

```
/usr/share/unity-greeter/custom_ubuntu_on_wayland_badge.png
```

or:

```
/usr/share/unity-greeter/ubuntu_on_wayland_badge.png
```

In other words: how should I call the "wayland" icon to make sure that is seen?

Ubuntu 20.10 Groovy Gorilla.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I've been lucky with several renaming attempts. The file must be called:

```
/usr/share/unity-greeter/custom_ubuntu-wayland_badge.png
```